# Событие мыши не может быть обработано для специфичной платформы

Tags: java, windows-10, swt

Следующий код был успешно протестирован тестовом окружении, под управлением JRE той же самой версии, что и Target JDK Platform (JDK 1.6.0.45 32 Bit) на `Windows 10 Enterprise 64 Bit`

На той же машине в интеграционном  окружении под управлением развернутого с помощью Java Web Start  `JRE` другой версии `1.8_60 32 Bit` у меня возникли проблемы с обработкой событиия прокрутки колесика мыши: согласно логам обрабочик на интеграции не вызывается.

Проблема воспроизводится на других машинах с теми же версиями ОС и JRE.

Как я могу локализовать и решить проблему?

- Является ли проблема с версией `JRE`?
- Является ли это проблемой CCombo?

```java
// Класс скомпилирован на JDK 1.6
// Target Platform не может быть изменен технически
public class CComboUtils {
    public static void disableMouseWheel(final CCombo combo) {
        // Выполняется как в тестовом окружении (jdk 1.6), так и в интеграционном окружении (jre 1.8)
        combo.addListener(SWT.MouseWheel, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                // Выполняется в тестовом окружении. НЕ выполняется в интеграционном окружении
                System.out.println("CComboUtils.disableMouseWheel::handleEvent");
                if (event.count > 0) {
                    System.out.println("CComboUtils.disableMouseWheel::handleEvent::handleScrollUp");
                    handleScrollUp(combo, event);
                } else if (event.count < 0) {
                // Выполняется в тестовом окружении. НЕ выполняется в интеграционном окруженииSystem.out.println("CComboUtils.disableMouseWheel::handleEvent::handleScrollDown");
                    handleScrollDown(combo, event);
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
    
    public static void handleScrollUp(CCombo combo, Event event) {
        if (combo.isFocusControl()) {
            // Выполняется в тестовом окружении. НЕ выполняется в интеграционном
            // could be a legitimate key event, let CCombo handle it
            return;
        }
        
        event.doit = false;
    }

    public static void handleScrollDown(CCombo combo, Event event) {
        if (combo.isFocusControl()) {
            // Выполняется в тестовом окружении. НЕ выполняется в интеграционном
            // could be a legitimate key event, let CCombo handle it
            return;
        }
        
        event.doit = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Версию JRE 1.8_60 на интеграции поменять очень сложно даже для целей тестирования

Comment: Тут проблема похоже в совместимости разных версий SWT с разными версиями OS и JRE. У меня есть кросс-платформенное десктопное  приложение на SWT, написанное 5 лет назад. Тогда, когда я его писал, была масса геморроя с Linux'ом и MacOS -- очень многое было не так, как в Windows -- порядок вызова слушателей, содержание полей событий и т.п. Как-то поборол, потом вышла новая версия Linux, и опять всё сломалось. С MacOS вообще беда. За пять лет со дня релиза я уже год угробил на адаптации к новым версиям ОС и SWT. Старая SWT несовместима с новой OS, новая SWT несовместима со старой JRE, и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Сменилось две версии JRE. Конечно там уже за это время могли удалить событие и заменить его совершенно другим, "прогрессивным". Если таргетовая версия готового продукта - `1.8`, то и пиши на `1.8`, в чём проблема... Сейчас почти везде `1.8` юзается: `1.6` уже дико сложно найти, только на каких-нибудь сайтах)) Теперь код слушателя событий колёсика мыши выглядит примерно так:

```
(Любой JComponent).addMouseWheelListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
});
```

Попробуй поменять версию JRE и JDK на более новую.

Comment: Указанное решение не применимо для указанной библиотеки. Это не Swing, а SWT, о чем было указано в тегах